# Hitting Digest already called on cryptoJS during unit testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, cryptojs

```js
import crypto from 'crypto';

export const getChecksum: (_: PathLike) => Promise<string> = (path: PathLike) =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    const hash = crypto.createHash('md5');
    const input = fs.createReadStream(path);

    input.on('data', chunk => {
      hash.update(chunk);
    });

    input.on('close', () => {
      resolve(hash.digest('hex'));
    });
  });
```

Given the function, it can accept a file path, and perform `hash.update` while streaming the file, I'm trying to write an unit test like below

```js
describe('getChecksum()', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    vol.reset();
  });

  it('should generate consistent checksum', async () => {
    vol.fromJSON(
      {
        './some/README.md': '1',
        './some/index.js': '2',
      },
      '/app'
    );

    const result = await getChecksum('/app/some/index.js');
    expect(result).toBe('c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c');
  });
});
```

From the Unit Test above, assertion was able to perform correctly, however, I'm hitting error below

```sh
  ● getChecksum() › should generate consistent checksum

    Error [ERR_CRYPTO_HASH_FINALIZED] [ERR_CRYPTO_HASH_FINALIZED]: Digest already called

      63 |
      64 |     input.on('close', () => {
    > 65 |       resolve(hash.digest('hex'));
         |                    ^
      66 |     });
      67 |   });
      68 |
```

Not too sure which part has gone wrong?

Comment: For clarity, this code is *only* failing when being executed within the context of this test?

Comment: @esqew: yes that's right, it is working fine when I'm executing it in NodeJS scripts

Comment: Commenting out your references to `vol` (which I assume is an instance of a `memfs` class) and stripping down to the most basic logic, I can't reproduce using [this Repl.it](https://replit.com/@esqew/BlankStudiousKeychanger#index.test.js). Is it possible that `memfs` is playing games with the `readStream` causing it to hash earlier than expected? Can you update your code to make this a true [mre] by providing some code that can accurately reproduce this condition (likely with some sort of mock of your `memfs` calls)?